# Binding const& of temporary: No compiler warning?

Tags: c++, const-reference

I have a `TestClass` with a `const&` member variable. I know from various places and own experiences that it is a bad idea to initialize this `const&` with the reference to a temporary value. So I was quite suprised that the following code will compile fine (tested with `gcc-4.9.1`, `clang-3.5`, and `scan-build-3.5`) but fail to run properly.

```
class TestClass {
  public:
    // removing the "reference" would remove the temporary-problem
    const std::string &d;

    TestClass(const std::string &d)
        : d(d) {
        // "d" is a const-ref, cannot be changed at all... if it is assigned some
        // temporary value it is mangled up...
    }
};

int main() {

    // NOTE: the variable "d" is a
    // temporary, whose reference is not valid... what I don't get in the
    // moment: why does no compiler warn me?
    TestClass dut("d");

    // and printing what we got:
    std::cout << "beginning output:\n\n";
    // this will silently abort the program (gcc-4.9.1) or be empty
    // (clang-3.5) -- don't know whats going on here...
    std::cout << "dut.d: '" << dut.d << "'\n";
    std::cout << "\nthats it!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Why does none of the two compilers warn me at compile-time? See also this [ideone](http://ideone.com/NDI9Gw), with some more testing going on.

Comment: Constant references are valid as long as the reference variable is in scope and valid.

Comment: And a note on terminology, `"d"` is not a variable, it's a string literal. However, passing it to a function expecting a `std::string` *creates* a temporary `std::string` object.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but doesn't binding a const& to a temporary extend the lifetime of that temporary if required?

Comment: @Bathsheba Doesn't temporary last until the end of constructor, invoking UB later when the reference member variable is used?

Comment: @Bathsheba No.  Initializing a reference with a temporary extends the temporary's lifetime in most cases (but not in an initializer list of a constructor), but if the reference is initialized with another reference, it has no effect on the lifetime of any temporary.

Comment: @JamesKanze In most cases? It only happens for local references, does it not?

Comment: @FredOverflow No.  It happens in most cases; the only exceptions are temporaries in an initialization list, and temporaries which initialize function arguments (which last until the end of the full expression).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No warning as no offense:

local `const` references prolong the lifespan of the variable.

The standard specifies such behavior in §8.5.3/5, [dcl.init.ref], the section on initializers of reference declarations. The lifetime extension is not transitive through a function argument. §12.2/5 [class.temporary]:

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is
>   the complete object to a subobject of which the temporary is bound
>   persists for the lifetime of the reference except as specified below.
>   A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s
>   ctor-initializer (§12.6.2 [class.base.init]) persists until the
>   constructor exits. A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a
>   function call (§5.2.2 [expr.call]) persists until the completion of
>   the full expression containing the call.

You can have a look at [gotw-88](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) for an extended and more readable discussion on this topic.

### Undefined Behaviour

So is it your code correct? Nope, and its execution will lead to undefined behaviour. The real problem in your code snapshot is that the Undefined Behaviour is caused by the mix of two perfectly **legal** operations: the call of the constructor passing a temporary object (whose life spans inside the constructor block) and the binding of the reference in the constructor definition.

The compiler is not *smart enough* to detect this explosive statement combination, so this is why you don't get any warning.

Comment: _The compiler is not smart enough to detect this explosive statement combination_ -- I spent some time writing clang-based tooling, and I wonder if `scan-build` could be made aware of this. It is not yet.

Comment: References don't extend the lifetime; initializing a reference with a temporary does, and not just for local variables.  The clause you cite delimits the exceptions, but that's not the issue here, since he doesn't initialize the class member with a temporary.

Comment: @JamesKanze I just wanted to point out that the operation passing a temporary to the constructor is perfectly legal...

Comment: "A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (§12.6.2 [class.base.init]) persists until the constructor exits" -- Wow.  I can't think of a single situation in which this standard-mandated behaviour is desirable.  A reference member initialised this way is *guaranteed* to cause UB if accessed in any way by any later method call.  This situation can be trivially detected at compile time, so why aren't compilers told to give an error instead of generating almost-certainly-buggy code?

Comment: @j_random_hacker I don't know about "desirable", but the standard is also concerned with "implementable", and it's hard to see how you could implement extending the lifetime of the temporary to match that of the class.  (I agree that compilers could give a warning.  Don't they?)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I hope they give a warning.  In this case I wasn't suggesting that compilers should be required to correctly extend the lifetime (which would be nice, but may well require Herculean analysis), rather that they should be required to give an error message (which only requires very basic analysis).  The goal is to make the set of programs that give *neither* defined behaviour nor a compiler error as small as possible.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Why it's not an error?  Good question: I can't think of any reason why you might want to do it.  But orthogonality and the principle that you should give a programmer all the rope he needs to shoot himself in the foot are probably at the base of it.

Comment: The second statement ("only local") is false.  The standard doesn't make this restriction, and a temporary used to initialize a reference with static lifetime will last the length of the program.

Answer (score 3):

Binding a `const &` to a temporary is valid and the compiler will ensure that the temporary will live at least as long as the reference. This allows you to do things like pass string literals into functions expecting a `const std::string &`.

In your case however you are copying that reference and thus the lifetime guarantee no longer holds. Your constructor exits and the temporary is destroyed and you are left with a reference to invalid memory.

Comment: With regards to the second sentence: passing literals to a function taking a `std::string const&` doesn't require extending the lifetime; the lifetime of a temporary is (with a couple of exceptions) until the end of the full expression.  At which time you will have returned from the function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is no single point in which a warning would be warranted. It's only the combination of the call of the constructor and its implementation that leads to Undefined Behaviour.

If you consider just the constructor:

```
class TestClass {
  public:
    const std::string &d;

    TestClass(const std::string &d)
        : d(d)
    {}
};
```

There's nothing wrong here, you got a reference and you're storing one. Here's an example of perfectly valid use:

```
class Widget {
  std::string data;
  TestClass test;

public:
  Widget() : data("widget"), test(data)
  {}
};
```

If you consider just the call site:

```
//Declaration visible is:
TestClass(const std::string &d);

int main() {
    TestClass dut("d");
}
```

Here, the compiler doesn't "see" (in the general case) the *definition* of the constructor. Imagine an alternative:

```
struct Gadget {
  std::string d;

  Gadget(cosnt std::string &d) : d(d) {}
};

int main()
{
  Gadget g("d");
}
```

Surely you wouldn't want a warning here either.

To summarise, both the call site and the constructor implementation are perfectly usable as-is. It's only their combination which causes issues, but that combination is beyond the context a compiler can reasonably use to emit warnings.

Comment: And the use of the member function later on - is it valid?

Comment: @BЈовић Of which member function? Can you clarify?

Comment: `std::cout << "dut.d: '" << dut.d << "'\n";` He is using the reference in main(). As far as I know, that is UB, just not sure in this case (I still think it is ub)

Comment: @BЈовић My answer mentions there's UB, and my impression was that the OP knows as much. I interpreted the question as "Why is there no warning for this invalid program?", not as "Is this valid?"

Answer (score 1):

```
TestClass(const std::string &d1)
    : d(d1) {

TestClass dut("d");
```

I guess following is happening logically:-

1) Your string literal `("d")` would be implicitly converted to std::string (  Let's give it a name `'x'` ).

2) So, `'x'` is a temporary which is bound to `d1` here. Lifetime of this temporary is extended to lifetime of your `d1`. Although that string literal would always be alive till the end of program.

3) Now you're making `'d' refer to 'd1'`.

4) At the end of your constructor `d1's` lifetime is over and so is `d's`.

All compiler's are not so clever to figure out these minor glitches...